# Encoded password does not look like BCrypt

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring Boot, Spring Security, OAuth2 and JWT to authenticate my application, but I keep getting this nasty error and I don't have any idea what is wrong. My `CustomDetailsService` class:

```
@Service
public class CustomDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomDetailsService.class);

    @Autowired
    private UserBO userBo;

    @Autowired
    private RoleBO roleBo;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        AppUsers appUsers = null;
        try {
            appUsers = this.userBo.loadUserByUsername(username);
            System.out.println("========|||=========== "+appUsers.getUsername());
        }catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e){
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Wrong username");
        }catch(DataAccessException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Database Error");
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Unknown Error");
        }

        if(appUsers == null){
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Bad credentials");
        }
        logger.info("Username: "+appUsers.getUsername());
        return buildUserFromUserEntity(appUsers);
    }

    private User buildUserFromUserEntity(AppUsers authUsers) {
        Set<UserRole> userRoles = authUsers.getUserRoles();

        boolean enabled = true;
        boolean accountNotExpired = true;
        boolean credentialsNotExpired = true;
        boolean accountNotLocked = true;

        if (authUsers.getAccountIsActive()) {
            try {
                if(authUsers.getAccountExpired()){
                    accountNotExpired = true;
                } else if (authUsers.getAccountIsLocked()) {
                    accountNotLocked = true;
                } else {
                    if (containsRole((userRoles), roleBo.findRoleByName("FLEX_ADMIN"))){
                        accountNotLocked = false;
                    }
                }
            }catch(Exception e){
                enabled = false;
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }else {
            accountNotExpired = false;
        }
        // convert model user to spring security user
        String username = authUsers.getUsername();
        String password = authUsers.getPassword();

        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = buildUserAuthority(userRoles);

        User springUser = new User(username, password,enabled, accountNotExpired, credentialsNotExpired, accountNotLocked, authorities);
        return springUser;
    }
}
```

`OAuth2Config`:

```
@Configuration
public class OAuth2Config extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter tokenConverter() {
        JwtAccessTokenConverter tokenConverter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        tokenConverter.setSigningKey(PRIVATE_KEY);
        tokenConverter.setVerifierKey(PUBLIC_KEY);
        return tokenConverter;
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtTokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JwtTokenStore(tokenConverter());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpointsConfigurer) throws Exception {
        endpointsConfigurer.authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                .tokenStore(tokenStore())
                .accessTokenConverter(tokenConverter());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer securityConfigurer) throws Exception {
        securityConfigurer.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()").checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory()
                .withClient(CLIENT_ID)
                .secret(CLIENT_SECRET)
                .scopes("read","write")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("password","refresh_token")
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(20000)
                .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(20000);
    }
}
```

`SecurityConfig`:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    CustomDetailsService customDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder encoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    @Autowired
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(customDetailsService).passwordEncoder(encoder());
        System.out.println("Done...finito");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.NEVER);
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
}
```

No error message except:

```
Hibernate: select appusers0_.id as id1_2_, appusers0_.account_expired as account_2_2_, appusers0_.account_is_active as account_3_2_, appusers0_.account_is_locked as account_4_2_, appusers0_.bank_acct as bank_acc5_2_, appusers0_.branch_id as branch_i6_2_, appusers0_.bvn as bvn7_2_, appusers0_.create_date as create_d8_2_, appusers0_.created_by as created_9_2_, appusers0_.email as email10_2_, appusers0_.email_verified_code as email_v11_2_, appusers0_.gender as gender12_2_, appusers0_.gravatar_url as gravata13_2_, appusers0_.is_deleted as is_dele14_2_, appusers0_.lastname as lastnam15_2_, appusers0_.middlename as middlen16_2_, appusers0_.modified_by as modifie17_2_, appusers0_.modified_date as modifie18_2_, appusers0_.orgnization_id as orgniza19_2_, appusers0_.password as passwor20_2_, appusers0_.phone_no as phone_n21_2_, appusers0_.surname as surname22_2_, appusers0_.token_expired as token_e23_2_, appusers0_.username as usernam24_2_ from users appusers0_ where appusers0_.username=?
Tinubu
2018-03-31 01:42:03.255  INFO 4088 --- [nio-8072-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2018-03-31 01:42:03.255  INFO 4088 --- [nio-8072-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2018-03-31 01:42:03.281  INFO 4088 --- [nio-8072-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 26 ms
2018-03-31 01:42:03.489  WARN 4088 --- [nio-8072-exec-2] o.s.s.c.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder     : Encoded password does not look like BCrypt
```

My entity model classes are:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="USERS")
@DynamicUpdate
public class AppUsers {

    @Id
    @Column(name="ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @ApiModelProperty(notes = "The user auto generated identity", required = true)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="username")
    @ApiModelProperty(notes = "The username parameter", required = true)
    private String username;

    @Column(name="password")
    @ApiModelProperty(notes = "The password parameter", required = true)
    private String password;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="appUsers")
    private Set<UserRole> userRoles;

'''''' setters and getters
}
```

`Role` entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ROLE")
public class Role {

    @javax.persistence.Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "role_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long Id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String roleName;

   @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="role")
    private Set<UserRole> userRoles;

   //getters and setters

}
```

`UserRole` entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="USER_ROLE")
@DynamicUpdate
public class UserRole   implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6128016096756071383L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @ApiModelProperty(notes = "The userrole auto generated identity", required = true)
    private long id;

    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne//(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private AppUsers appUsers;

    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne//(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private Role role;

   // getters and setters
}
```

My password in the database is properly encrypted Spring security BCrypt and it datatype is varchar(255) which is larger than 60.

Comment: @Min Hyoung Hong.. The code ran well until I need to pass the authentication credentials. the only error it throws is: (Encoded password does not look like BCrypt)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

`BCryptPasswordEncoder` shows this warning when it fails to match a raw password with an encoded password.

The hashed password  might be `$2b` or `$2y` now.

And there is a bug in `Spring Security` that has a regex always looking for `$2a`. Put a debug point at the `matches()` method in the `BCryptPasswordEncoder.class`.

Comment: Im running into this problem right now. I've hashed passwords with online tools, and if hashed password starts with $2y or $2b i got 'Encoded password does not look like BCrypt'. The only way i found to avoid this error is having hashed passwords that starts with $2a

Comment: FYI The Bug was tracked on GitHub: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/3320. It seems like a PR was merged in October 2018 (3 Years after Bug Report and 4 Years after BCrypt update). It will probably be released with a new Spring Security Version (5.2.0)

Comment: Spring-core-security version 5.0.11, class BCryptPasswordEncoder, method "matches" using "private Pattern BCRYPT_PATTERN = Pattern
   .compile("\\A\\$2a?\\$\\d\\d\\$[./0-9A-Za-z]{53}");" will be fall in block: if (!BCRYPT_PATTERN.matcher(encodedPassword).matches()) {
   logger.warn("Encoded password does not look like BCrypt");
   return false;
  }

Comment: for me culprit was using char[] for storing password

Comment: For people coming from any tutorial, the password field in DB should be longer in your table. Set it to varchar(100) and see if it works.

Answer (score 41):

Can you double check your client secret is encoded?

```
@Override
public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer configurer) throws Exception {
    configurer
            .inMemory()
            .withClient(clientId)
            .secret(passwordEncoder.encode(clientSecret))
            .authorizedGrantTypes(grantType)
            .scopes(scopeRead, scopeWrite)
            .resourceIds(resourceIds);
}
```

Comment: Man this worked for me! Can you please explain why we also need to encode client password?

Answer (score 16):

The PasswordEncoder should be set like this:

```
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
}
```

Comment: You're right.. but this leads to another issue `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: There is no PasswordEncoder mapped for the id "null"`

Comment: You can bCrypt client secret like {bcrypt}$2a...... Hope fully it's work!

Comment: @Pra_A how did you go around this ```java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: There is no PasswordEncoder mapped for the id "null"``` am getting the same error

Answer (score 12):

When oauth2 dependecncies moved to cloud, I started facing this issue. Earlier it was part of security framework :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Now it is part of cloud framework :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-oauth2</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

So if you are using cloud dependency (Finchley.RELEASE) then you may need to encode the secret like below :

```
@Override
public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
    clients
            .inMemory()
            .withClient("clientapp")
            .authorizedGrantTypes("password","refresh_token")
            .authorities("USER")
            .scopes("read", "write")
            .resourceIds(RESOURCE_ID)
            .secret(passwordEncoder.encode("SECRET"));
}
```

Answer (score 9):

As of today, with Spring Boot 2.1.7.RELEASE, I am still experiencing this issue. 
I was using some online tools which gave me hashes starting with $2b or $2y, 
which Spring's `BCryptPasswordEncoder` does not allow:

```
public class BCryptPasswordEncoder implements PasswordEncoder {
    private Pattern BCRYPT_PATTERN = Pattern
            .compile("\\A\\$2a?\\$\\d\\d\\$[./0-9A-Za-z]{53}");
...
```

*Solution*: use `BCryptPasswordEncoder` class to encode the password:

```
BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
System.out.println(encoder.encode("admin"));
```

And then:

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
        throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("admin")
            .password("{bcrypt}$2a$10$6CW1agMzVzBhxDzK0PcxrO/cQcmN9h8ZriVEPy.6DJbVeyATG5mWe")
            .roles("ADMIN");
}
```

Answer (score 7):

For my own similar scenario I just encoded the password like this `passwordEncoder().encode("password")` instead of raw String `"password"`:

```java
authenticationManagerBuilder
  .inMemoryAuthentication()
  .withUser("user")
  // Just changed here
  .password(passwordEncoder().encode("password"))
  .roles("USER");


@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
  return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Update field `client_secret` in table `oauth_client_details` with `BCryptPasswordEncoder` in case you migrate spring boot from 1x to 2x. To encode secret use:

```
    BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    String password = "12345678";
    String encodedPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(password);

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Password is         : " + password);
    System.out.println("Encoded Password is : " + encodedPassword);
    System.out.println();

    boolean isPasswordMatch = passwordEncoder.matches(password, encodedPassword);
    System.out.println("Password : " + password + "   isPasswordMatch    : " + isPasswordMatch);
```

Answer (score 5):

The best way to identify this problem "**Encoded password does not look like BCrypt**" is setup a break porint in class **org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder**. And then check the root cause for the warnning.

```
if (!BCRYPT_PATTERN.matcher(encodedPassword).matches()) {
    logger.warn("Encoded password does not look like BCrypt");
    return false;
}
```

Comment: For my error message "Encoded password does not look like BCrypt" . The length of encode password is 60 byte. But the column password in database is 100. So I have change the column password from char to varchar to fix this issue.

Comment: my database is db2 on iseries.

Answer (score 3):

BCryptPasswordEncoder does not strip the {bcrypt} id, but DelegatingPasswordEncoder do it. When I define explicitly BCryptPasswordEncoder as an encoder for DaoAuthenticationProvider it calls matches method on BCryptPasswordEncoder (without id strip), but not on DelegatingPasswordEncoder (with id strip).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error and it was because of the datatype of the password column, 
this column was length blank fixed (CHARACTER), so make sure You're using a VARCHAR datatype or else change the length to 60 for you password column.

Answer (score 2):

Please check if your method `UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)` returns valid `UserDetail` object. If Returned object is null / object with invalid values then also you will see this error.

Answer (score 2):

In Spring Security 5, the default encoder is DelegatingPasswordEncoder, which required Password Storage Format.

Read [this](https://spring.io/blog/2017/11/01/spring-security-5-0-0-rc1-released#password-storage-format)

```
    private PasswordEncoder delegateEncoder =
            PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception{
            clients
                    .jdbc(dataSource)
                    .passwordEncoder(delegateEncoder);
    }
```

Generate the `password` or `secret` code using default encoder which is  `DelegatingPasswordEncoder`

```
System.out.println(delegateEncoder.encode("123123"));
// it generates the encoded code something like this: 
// {bcrypt}$2a$10$0aISzamI0jBCVTxONzJlHOk7O7QS.XPFIheLVhXultVa9Ju7SarZ6
```

Answer (score 2):

1. In case you've added "{bcrypt}" right before password, and not configured your app accordingly, you will get this error. Consider removing this.
2. If still not resolved, just set the column length of the user's password to 60( 68 if you've added {bcryt} at the beginning) Worked for me!

Comment: I also stumbled over this problem. I finally found out that my field in the DB was too long so that the PW returned from the DB bad trailing spaces, preventing a successful PW match.

Comment: I used the Spring CLI to generated a bcrypt password and stripping the {bcrypt} from thtat made the generated Spring login flow work.

Answer (score 2):

I had same issue and problem is that you should encode your inMemory password because when you click login form Spring Security take the extracted password from the HTTP Basic Auth header, **hash** it automatically and compare it with the hashed password from your UserDetails object. If both match, the user is successfully authenticated otherwise you will get this error.

For example ,

InMemory Password = "123"
passwordEncoder.encode("123")

Reference :  [link](https://www.marcobehler.com/guides/spring-security#:%7E:text=The%20short%20answer%3A,standards%20like%20OAuth2%20or%20SAML.)

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this error while doing a Spring Security Course.

My problem was that even though in the AuthenticationManager  I was using the encoding, e.g:

```
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }
```

The Problem was that I was not Encoding the Password when I was saving the Users!!
Example:

```
final Principal entity = new Principal(loginName, passwordEncoder.encode(pass), roles);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are likely missing this bean in your Security configuration `SecurityConfig`

```
@Bean
public DaoAuthenticationProvider getAuthenticationProvider() {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(customDetailsService);
    authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(encoder());
    return authenticationProvider;
}
```

Comment: The `UserDetaulsService` and the `PasswordEncoder` are already defined at `protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder)`. Isn't that enough?

Answer (score 0):

use noop in secret for tests.

```
@Override
public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
    clients.inMemory()
            .withClient("angular")
            .secret("{noop}@ngular0")
            .scopes("read", "write")
            .authorizedGrantTypes("password")
            .accessTokenValiditySeconds(1800);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got rid of this error message by using a long, 60 chars+ password e.g. CXPW3XT2vXwBZk9mYZ5eCrKPM8kXJC6bbwJQjtGq2NQRYQPzsvqTwYz8JvWhWD5KLrrUHHammBNV3tkkyA4U

Answer (score 0):

The UserDetails entity has to return the encoded password. This varies depending on the implementation.

```
class MyUserDetails: UserDetails {

    //...

    override fun getPassword(): String {
        return passwordEncoder().encode("aPassword")
    }

    private fun passwordEncoder(): PasswordEncoder {
        return BCryptPasswordEncoder()
    }

}
```

GL

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the empty spaces in password.

Try to trim your password while returning from your custom UserDetailsService class.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my bcrypt hash which started from `$2y` to `$2a` i.e. `$2y$12$0Evlz//oO` to `$2a$12$0Evlz//oO`  and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried all the solutions above, considering my usecase was different than this one in Spring Boot. In my case, I switched my DBMS from *MySQL to PostgreSQL*, and the app was working fine in case of MySQL, with login/logout feature working perfectly. But when I switched to *Postgres*, this error started showing in login functionality. I noticed in pgAdmin , that BCrypt passwords had extra spaces in the end, I even tried to manually remove those spaces, but that too rolled back the changes on its own every time.

Then finally I read somewhere that, *BCrypt encrypted text length is fixed i.e. 60 chars*. But my password field in Postgres was of 80 chars. I **simply changed the field length from 80 to 60 chars**. You can either do it using GUI, or from CLI, using **ALTER TABLE** command, whatever suits you.

Answer (score 0):

With the following code I get rid of this error

```
 @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer configurer) throws Exception {
        
        BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        String encodedPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(CLIENT_SECRET);

        configurer
                .inMemory()
                .withClient(CLIENT_ID)
                .secret(encodedPassword)
                .authorizedGrantTypes(GRANT_TYPE)
                .scopes(SCOPE_READ, SCOPE_WRITE)
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(ACCESS_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS).
                refreshTokenValiditySeconds(REFRESH_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS);
    }
```

So it is necessary to encode the secret

Answer (score 0):

For spring security 5 OAuth 2 Server, this is how I fixed it

```
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder delegatingPasswordEncoder() {
        Map<String, PasswordEncoder> encoders = new HashMap<>();
        encoders.put("bcrypt", new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
        DelegatingPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new DelegatingPasswordEncoder("bcrypt", encoders);
        passwordEncoder.setDefaultPasswordEncoderForMatches(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
        return passwordEncoder;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

lol spring rrr me
try this

```
 @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }


 @Bean
 public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
     return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing same issue:

In my case table's column length was 50 char only which was causing this issue later I modify column length to 100 as suggested in above and it worked for me.

```
ALTER TABLE `users`
    CHANGE COLUMN `password` `password` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL AFTER `enabled`;
```

Answer (score 0):

My views
bCryptEncoder.matches("rawString",encodedPwdFromDB);
This is the actual parameter need to check while passing the values

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).