# Login errors in spring boot: Encoded password does not look like BCrypt

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I ran my spring boot project in idea, register, then I have the problem when I login. It redirected to the "localhost:8080/login?error" and has the following in idea console

> Encoded password does not look like BCrypt

I've searched the answer in stackoverflow and saw this [the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49582971/encoded-password-does-not-look-like-bcrypt). But It seems to be useless to me because my configure extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter not AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter. My configure class is

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private WorkersRepository workersRepository;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/submit").access("hasRole('WORKER')")
            .anyRequest().permitAll()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
            .and()
            .rememberMe()
            .tokenValiditySeconds(4838400)
            .key("workerKey");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws         Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(new UserDetailsService() {
        @Override
        public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
            Worker worker = workersRepository.findByUsername(username);
            return workersRepository.findByUsername(username);
        }
    }).passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder()).and()
    .inMemoryAuthentication().passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder())
    .withUser("admin").password("123456").roles("ADMIN","WORKER");
    }
}
```

My Worker class is

```
@Entity
public class Worker implements UserDetails {

    private static final long serialversionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 5, max = 16, message = "{username.size}")
    private String username;
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 2, max = 30, message = "{firstName.size}")
    private String firstname;
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 2, max = 30, message = "{lastName.size")
    private String lastname;
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 5, max = 25,message = "{password.size}")
    private String password;
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 2, max = 30, message = "{profession,size}")
    private String profession;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getProfession() {
        return profession;
    }

    public void setProfession(String profession) {
        this.profession = profession;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    //UserDetails methods


    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return Arrays.asList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("WORKER"));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

My WorkersRepository is

```
package com.rieunity.workinghours;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface WorkersRepository extends JpaRepository<Worker, String> {
    Worker findByUsername(String username);
}
```

I did not login with user admin, I registered a new user in register.html and succeeded. Then I login in login page and failed with the error:

> Encoded password does not look like BCrypt

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've solved the problem. Since I encoded the password by using BCryptPasswordEncoder, I should store the password in this form. Hence the solution is adding

```
String encodedPassword = new BCryptPasswordEncoder().encode(worker.getPassword());
worker.setPassword(encodedPassword);
```

into the "/register" post request

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String registrationProcessing(@Valid Worker worker, Errors errors, RedirectAttributes model) {
    if(errors.hasErrors()) {
        return "registerForm";
    };
    String encodedPassword = new BCryptPasswordEncoder().encode(worker.getPassword());
    worker.setPassword(encodedPassword);
    workersRepository.save(worker);
    model.addAttribute("username", worker.getUsername());
    model.addFlashAttribute("worker", worker);
    return "redirect:/";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The password field for a BCrypt should be at least 60 character because the result hash has 60 char.

```
 @Size(min = 5, max = 60,message = "{password.size}")
 private String password;
```

Comment: did you change also the db column? (varchar(60) )

Comment: I ran it in idea and use the embedded h2 database. I open the h2 console but cannot find the embedded database url, hence I failed to look into the database and change it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same issue and solution is simple , first open online Bcrypt ecrypter site in browser :
https://www.dailycred.com/article/bcrypt-calculator
and first try in here.Java is use 12 number of rounds in Brcypt as default.You must use 12 ! not another number.